# Navicat not connecting to LocalDB

Tags: localdb, navicat

Suddenly, Navicat stopped connecting to LocalDB v11.0 database after working fine for a long time.

[image]

If I move the same .mdf to SQL server, Navicat connects to it just fine, but not when the file is on LocalDB.
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio instead connects fine to LocalDB as well.

I've tried reinstalling LocalDB and that didn't help. I also reinstalled Navicat and no help either.

Where to find the solution?